# Does declaring strongSelf from weakSelf before a block cause retain cycle

Tags: objective-c

Here is the block in question. Im wondering if declaring strongSelf outside of the block will introduce a retain cycle in anyway. The reason for setting up the strongSelf outside the block is that I'm worried that weakSelf will be deallocated before the completion block.

```
__weak CollectionView *weakSelf = self;
    CollectionView *strongSelf = weakSelf;
        [self
         performBatchUpdates:
            ^{
                strongSelf->_cellSet = [strongSelf performDeletions:[strongSelf deletionsTowards:destinationSet from:strongSelf->_cellSet] from:strongSelf->_cellSet];
                [(CollectionViewLayout *)strongSelf.collectionViewLayout setCellSet:strongSelf->_cellSet];
            }
         completion:
            ^(BOOL finished)
            {
                [strongSelf insertTowards:destinationSet];
            }];
```

Comment: yes, it will cause a retain cycle. you should fix your code so that `self` is not deallocated before the callbacks are invoked.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is just pointless. weakSelf is a weak reference to self. strongSelf is a strong reference to self. It is captured by the block, so the block now also has a strong reference to self (that's the difference when you use weakSelf in the block: When the block captures weakSelf, the block has a weak reference to self). Instead of using strongSelf in the block, it would be much easier to just use self - it will be exactly the same thing. You *might* confuse the compiler enough to not give you any warnings when you use strongSelf where you would have got a warning for using self (if that warning was appropriate).

Whether you cause a retain cycle: Depends on the code. If a copy of the two blocks is stored in the object self and not set back to nil when the completion blocks are called, then you have a retain cycle. If the two blocks are not stored anywhere then the strong reference to self goes away eventually.

The method that actually works well is to assign weakSelf to a strong reference strongSelf *inside* each block. And then the first thing that you do is to test once whether strongSelf is nil. In that case you know that self has been deallocated, and you need to think about what actions you would want to do in that case.

Comment: How does one go about using weakSelf if there are two blocks within a function, a batchUpdate and a completionHandler in this case, and make sure that the weakSelf pointer stays alive in between those two blocks.